# Is $\Bbb P(B_k|\bigcap_{j\in J}\bar{B_j}) \le \Bbb P(B_k)$ for any $J\subset I$ if $B_i, i\in I$ are positively correlated events?

Tags: probability

Under a probability space, given a set of events $B_i, i\in I$ where $I$ is an index set. If $\forall J\subset I, k\notin J$ we have $\Bbb P(B_k|\bigcap_{j\in J}B_j) \ge \Bbb P(B_k)$, then we say the events $B_i, i\in I$ are positively correlated. The problem is

> Is $\Bbb P(B_k|\bigcap_{j\in J}\bar{B_j}) \le \Bbb P(B_k)$ for any $J\subset I$? Prove the statement if it is ture, or show a counter example if it is false.

It is not hard to verify the statement holds for $|I|=2$ and $|J|=1$, i.e. if two events $A, B$ are positively correlated, $\Bbb P(A|B) \ge \Bbb P(A)$ as well ass $\Bbb P(B|A) \ge \Bbb P(B)$, then it is true that $\Bbb P(A|\bar B) \le \Bbb P(A)$ and $\Bbb P(B|\bar A) \le \Bbb P(B)$.

Can anyone provide some help for the general case? Thank you!